# Show unique Form under a unique div in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I have been working on a project and basically I have multiple div's contacting a student's info and buttons to edit certain fields in a database. With the code bellow, I click a button under a student's info and forms appear under every student. I only want a form to appear under the student that I wanted to edit. How do I do this? The toggle feature is working but like I said, the form appears under every student. How can I make the form appear under the student that I selected?

The way it appears is as follows:

Child Name: John Doe 
-more info here- 
[Button1] [Button2] [Button3]

Child Name: Ellie Smith 
-more info here- 
[Button1] [Button2] [Button3]

So on...

What I want to happen is this: If I click Button 1 under Ellie, a form should appear under her name like so:

Child Name: John Doe 
-more info here- 
[Button1] [Button2] [Button3]

Child Name: Ellie Smith 
-more info here- 
[Button1] [Button2] [Button3] 
[FORM HERE]

However, what is currently happening is this: If I click Button 1 under Ellie and then the form appears under both Ellie and John... Like this:

Child Name: John Doe 
-more info here- 
[Button1] [Button2] [Button3] 
[FORM HERE]

Child Name: Ellie Smith 
-more info here- 
[Button1] [Button2] [Button3] 
[FORM HERE]

How can I make it do what I want it to do, what am I doing wrong?

This is my **App.js** File:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      toggle: true,
      classroom: []
    };
    this.eventHandler = this.eventHandler.bind(this);
  }
  eventHandler(event) {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
        toggle: !prevState.toggle
      })
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/classroom')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(classroom => this.setState({ classroom }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
                <div className="wrapper">
                    <h1>Classroom</h1>
                    {this.state.classroom.map(classroom =>
                        <div className="child" key={classroom.id}>
              <p className="detail">Child's Name: <span className={classroom.childflagged}>{classroom.childsname}</span> <i title={classroom.flagreason} className={'fa fa-flag flag' + classroom.childflagged}></i><i title={classroom.starreason} className={'fa fa-star star' + classroom.starstudent}></i></p>
              <p className="detail">Parent's Phone Number: {classroom.parentsnumber}</p>
              <div className="actionMenu">
                <button className="flags" id={classroom.id} onClick={this.eventHandler}>Edit Flags</button>
                <button className="results">View Results</button>
                <button className="profile">View Profile</button>
              </div>
              <div className="actionForm">
                <div>
                  <form id={"flagform" + classroom.id} className={this.state.toggle ? 'hide' : ''} method="post" action="#" autoComplete="no">
                    <input type="text" name="flagreason" placeholder="Reason For Flag" />
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Changes" />
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
                </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're just toggling with a boolean. Every child will render the form when state.toggle is true. You could add a toggleIdxArray to your state. Pass the index to your eventHandler function.

In your state, add a toggleIdxArray.

```
this.state = {
      toggleIdxArray: [],
      classroom: []
    };
```

In your .map function, pass the idx to your event handler...

```
this.state.classroom.map((classroom, idx) => {
  <button className="flags" id={classroom.id} onClick={e => this.eventHandler(e, idx)}
})
```

In your event handler, update the array on state...

```
eventHandler(event, idx) {
    //copy over the current array
    let updatedArr = this.state.toggleIdxArray.slice();
    //check to see if the index is already there
    let checkIdx = updatedArr.indexOf(idx);
    //add it if it's not
    if (checkIdx === -1) updatedArr.push(idx);
    //remove it if it's already there
    else updatedArr.splice(checkIdx, 1);
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
        toggleIdxArray: updatedArr
      })
    );
  }
```

When rendering your form, check if the idx is in this.state.toggleIdxArray...

```
<form id={"flagform" + classroom.id} className={this.state.toggleIdxArray.includes(idx) ? '' : 'hide'}
```

You could also prevent the div with the form from rendering altogether with a ternary operator, rather than giving it a className of 'hide'.

```
{this.state.toggleIdxArray.includes(idx) ?
  (
<div className="actionForm">
    <div>
        <form id={"flagform" + classroom.id} method="post" action="#" autoComplete="no">
            <input type="text" name="flagreason" placeholder="Reason For Flag" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Changes" />
         </form>
    </div>
</div>
  ) : null
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! That worked fantastic! Great explanation too! Thanks again!

Comment: No problem! I updated the solution to allow multiple forms to render with the onClick eventHandler function. The original solution is probably better if you only want one form available at a time.